# Conditional statements for Title Tags in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I append certain words (depending on category) to title tags only in posts using conditional statements in functions.php?

For example if this ABC post is filed under Jakarta, so I'll like the title tag to show ABC | Emporium Jakarta

I've written the below code in functions.php but it doesn't work, I know I'm still missing some things. Help me out!

```
function append_title_tag() {
if(in_category('5')){
echo 'Emporium';
}
if(in_category('6')){
echo 'Emporium Jakarta';
}
if(in_category('7')){
echo 'Emporium Bali';
}
```

Comment: use like `if(isset(in_category('5')))`

Comment: what should I write as add filter below? or its not necessary to write an add filter?

Answer (score 1):

Try WordPress SEO Yoast Plugin, in which you can apply different title tag to individual page/ post. and you do not need any programming. you would get improve SEO by this plugin as well.
Try This plugin.
[wordpress Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)

Comment: Thanks Ash, I didn't want to use Yoast because I have very specific SEO needs that don't really need Yoast to fulfil. Yoast does a lot of things and is kinda heavy. But I get what you mean about the SEO improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('the_title','append_title_tag');

function append_title_tag($title) {

if(in_category('5')){
     echo $title.'| Emporium';
}else if(in_category('6')){ 
    echo $title.'|Emporium Jakarta';
}else if(in_category('7')){
    echo $title.'|Emporium Bali';
}else{
    echo $title;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had some errors, but I think its very close. Could it be I have to had some global posts code above?

Comment: yes try adding global $post , and then replace in_category(5,$post->ID);

Comment: Thanks Swapnil, I tried this but still got some errors. Managed to find a non code work around by using spreadsheet to re-import entries with a custom field to mass change my title tag. Thanks still!